# Python / Pandas - Merge columns with the same index in a single cell

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
                                     Dude
group_id                                                      
820125                            ARMANDO
820125                       LUIS OSWALDO
64907                            BERNARDO
64907                              SANDRO
64907                            VERONICA
```

I want it to look like this:

```
                                        Dudes
group_id                                                      
820125                 ARMANDO | LUIS OSWALDO
64907            BERNARDO | SANDRO | VERONICA
```

Already tried variations of merge, join and concat but wasn't successful. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group by index and `join` the column:

```
df.groupby(level=0).agg(' | '.join)
#                                   Dude
#group_id   
#64907      BERNARDO | SANDRO | VERONICA
#820125           ARMANDO | LUIS OSWALDO
```

To join a specific column only, use a dictionary in the `agg` function:

```
df.groupby(level=0).agg({"Dude": ' | '.join})
```

Same output as above.